# THREE.js not rendering image

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am just starting to learn js and THREE.js and have gotten through some basics. I am following a tutorial but cannot seem to get the image to load on my phone or computer.

I am doing this on Codepen but have also tried it via VS Code with the styles.css and image.png file in the same folder. When I open it in a browser it shows a black background and no image just as it does in CodePen. I’ve been at this for hours and just don’t know enough to figure out what’s wrong.

Here’s the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbu98QxRH81KkLTN00OXhD8Y-pRVgTCnM

TIME = 3:58 is when the image should load.

Here’s my code so far

```
let scene, lightDir, lightAmb, camera, width = window.innerWidth, height = window.innerHeight, renderer, portalGeo, portalMat;

function initScene() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  
  lightDir = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff,0.5);
  lightDir.position.set(0,0,30);
  scene.add(lightDir);
  
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
  camera.position.z = 1000;
  scene.add(camera);
  
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth , window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
  
  particleSetup();
}
function particleSetup() {
  let loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  
  loader.load("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/17wSPGemFtp1HD_qx8MRYD1QAczIEZjXYiTNXuxNXC6lGM4kbZSPdez2kuHHZB4wpIYMdWFBb2F-L6MjdwyM1n3s13OM4BKIxW2K35y6rFC65DRCqckm7mvWZ708snikmYLTHny3rQ=s256-p-k", function (texture){
    portalGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(350,350);
    portalMat = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
      map:texture,
      transparent:true
    });
    
    let particle = new THREE.Mesh(portalGeo,portalMat);
    particle.position.set(2,2,2);
    scene.add(particle);
    
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
  });
  
}
initScene();
```

And here’s the Pen
https://codepen.io/jfirestorm44/pen/GRqRReL

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Access to image at ... from origin ... has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: take a different image, e.g. from imgur.com, it was set cors headers for cross origin requests

Comment: Well that’s interesting as I’ve always used that method to get images onto my projects in Codepen. I even tried the image link address directly from tutorials website with no luck. I will try out another image hosting site when I get off work today. 

I appreciate the help.

Comment: So I created an IMGUR and uploaded the picture. This is the link it gave me https://imgur.com/a/9jPOR01 but when I put that into the js I still don’t get the picture. Anything else I can try in order to get it to work?

Comment: use link on picture, not on page